# Automated way to know which hardware in my company has been used by a certain laptop

Tags: windows

In Windows 10, is there an automated way to know which hardware in my company is being used by a certain laptop?
For example, knowing which mouse, which keyboard, etc. has been used or ever connected to a certain computer...
Is this being logged somewhere in Windows? The serial number or brand of the devices connected?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Of course there are ways to collect hardware summaries from an entire fleet of company laptops. But this site is [not well suited for *product recommendations*](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @anx you obviously didn't read the post properly - the question is about HISTORY log of connected devices! Not just simple inventory.

Comment: "Is this being logged somewhere in Windows?" no, there is no total device-history in windows. You will have to use other product to achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USBDeview utility is what you are looking for. It can also connect to a remote computer

Comment: This is great, @Vitas. What about other peripherals that were never connected via USB, such as external monitors... Is there a way to see the history of different monitors that have connected to a specific device?

Comment: well that's a great question... but I don't know :-] Anyway given that all hardware is visible in device manager it means it is in the registry. You can try finding where it is and see if the values stay there after you switch monitor for example. Then you could make some script to read those registries I suppose